# Modal view Controller not transparent after showing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When i use  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
and while animation not ending it looks  with a transparent background[image]

But when it's loaded it is not transparent
[image]

Comment: Try setting opacity of self.view background colour to 40%.

Comment: alpha is 0.3, backgound color = clear color